# Create a custom grid like control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Hi Im wondering how I can create a grid like control with datasource property. I want to draw the row columns using Graphic object in c# but will able to click on them to alter values.

```
+--------------------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+--------------------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+--------------------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Thanks

Comment: Unless you are trying to become an expert on designing custom controls, I'd advise against it, it's very complex, and there are many freely available grid controls out there.

Comment: Why would you want to reinvent the wheel when it exist under every particular technology with many variations and options

Comment: Use the listview control, it gives you the option to databind (as you requested) and a lot of freedom as to how the "rows" should look. You can drop any other control in it's template and bind it to the data.